# Mongodb shell is giving an error while connecting?

Tags: server, services, database, mongodb

When you try to connect to mongodb it is giving a following error:

root@ip-10-87-37-28:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
Fri Mar  8 07:40:11 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed

however it is not giving any error while starting the mongodb service.

To go through mongodb log please click [here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5595283/)

Please feel free to ask if any of you need any other information. Thanks in advance.

please click [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5595455/) for the update log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log files show the server starting up and then immediately shutting down with the error:

```
Fri Mar  8 09:14:22 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::file_size: No such file or directory: "/mongodb_data/database/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/METRICS.12", terminating
```

Your client won't be able to connect until you have successfully started up the server.